# See the balance without load the transaction history

Tags: transactions, wallet.dat

Let's say I have a wallet.dat with several transactions, is there a way to see only my current balance without load all transactions in the wallet.dat?

I would like to achieve something like this because that would be lighter to load on my computer.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, if you know the addresses of your wallet, you can look it up in a Bitcoin block explorer, and find the current balance of each address. There are also wallets, like Electrum, that will use third party nodes to track your balance, but cryptographically verify everything to ensure the third party node cannot lie to you.

Comment: But I need to use the Bitcoin core, I would like to load only my balance without the transaction history in Bitcoin core.

Comment: Then that isn't possible, because in order for a full node to calculate your address balance it has to load your transaction history to add up your transactions.

Comment: Yes, but unfortunately when you have a wallet.dat with too many transactions, that is a problem, because the wallet.dat will be very slow, and therefore it takes too much time to load it.